# How does a Windows Notepad display multiple fonts?

Tags: fonts, notepad

What I have known is, Notepad can display texts with a particular font only. But recently I pasted some texts from MS Word which were in Segoe UI font into the notepad which contains other texts too. Both fonts are displayed correctly. How does it happen? If I paste a different text with a different font other than Seoge, say for example, Impact, it is not displayed in Impact font. It may be a basic thing. But I could not understand how does it happen in a Notepad?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPdEP.png)

Comment: I  if it's just [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segoe#:~:text=Segoe%20UI%20Symbol%20is%20a,to%20respective%20Unicode%20code%20points.

Comment: ❶❷❸❹❺ÖƜΨ۝ was directly taken from the character map of windows. It is well displayed in notepad. Seoge UI Symbol seems to be unicode. But "Seoge UI" ?

Answer (score 0):

What you see there in Notepad is actually plain un-formatted text as expected. Like you said, notepad displays text in a single font only. The WONDER word in your image contains special characters or symbols. You can access the full range of characters/symbols in Word by going to Insert, Symbol, More Symbols. There you can find all of the thousands of special characters/symbols not shown directly on your keyboard. Many if not all should paste into Notepad the same as they do in Word, un-formatted of course. Notepad just strips out the formatting (colors, bold, size, etc) but it won't change a text symbol since it is a character.